# How would I select a specific component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components

I have a situation where I have an array with 3 values:

```
const dogArray = [randomDog(), randomDog(), correctName].sort()
```

I'm creating a component for each element in that array:

```
const renderButtons = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {dogArray.map((dog, index) => 
        <DogNameComponent 
          key={index} 
          submitAnswer={() => this.submitAnswer(correctName, dog)} 
          name={dog}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

How could I access the `DogNameComponent` that was created from the `correctName` element in that `dogArray`?

Using `React`+`Redux`

Comment: What do you mean by `access` ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: would like to target it and change its properties/style it

Comment: Do you mean change the props sent to it ?

Comment: So basically I'm creating a quizz and my code creates three buttons, 1 of them is the 'correct' button, and I'm looking for a way to style it differently than the other two

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options.
Putting your answers in different objects and setting one value to `true` for the correct answer :

```
const dogArray = [{ answer: randomDog() }, { answer: randomDog() }, { answer: correctName, correct: true}].sort()
```

Now that we tweaked the data structure, the default `sort` function will not work anymore so we will have to take the right values to compare in your objects :

```
sort((a, b) => a.answer > b.answer)
```

You are now aware of which object is the right one in your `map` and can send this info back to the component's props to style it :

```
{dogArray.map((dog, index) =>
        <DogNameComponent
            key={index}
            submitAnswer={() => this.submitAnswer(correctName, dog.answer)}
            name={dog.answer}
            isCorrect={dog.correct}
        />
    )
}
```

Or setting it in an array before deconstructing it :

```
const dogArray = [[randomDog()], [randomDog()], [correctName, true]].sort()
```

The sorting : `sort(([a], [b]) => a > b)`

Mapping function :

```
{dogArray.map(([answer, correct], index) =>
        <DogNameComponent
            key={index}
            submitAnswer={() => this.submitAnswer(correctName, answer)}
            name={answer}
            isCorrect={correct}
        />
    )
}
```

The child component will now know if it is the right answer, this value will be accessible in `this.props.correct`.

---

EDIT

Well, now that I think of it, maybe there is a WAY simpler option :

```
{dogArray.map((dog, index) => 
    <DogNameComponent 
      key={index} 
      submitAnswer={() => this.submitAnswer(correctName, dog)} 
      name={dog}
      correct={dog === correctName}
    />
)}
```

No changes to your array required.